# Measuring the effect of a linear transformation on the result

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have an unknown vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, a known orthogonal matrix $\Phi\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, a known matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} (m \le n)$, and a known vector $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$ where $A\Phi x = b$.  I want to know if a scalar $\alpha$ can be computed such that
$$
\|A\Phi x\|_2^2=\alpha\|b\|_2^2
$$
or
$$
x^T\Phi^TA^TA\Phi x = \alpha b^Tb
$$

and under what conditions that is possible, if any.  I know, for example, that if $m=n$ and $A$ was orthogonal, $\alpha=1$, but I am more interested in the case where $m\lt n$.  I'd much prefer to do it without solving for $x$.  Thanks in advance for your help.

**Oops, I posed the question incorrectly.**

I really meant:

$$
\|x\|_2^2=\alpha\|b\|_2^2
$$

Experimentally, it seems like it should at least be bounded when $A$ and $x$ are a randomly generated matrix and vector of a fixed size.

Comment: Welcome to our site

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the orthogonal matrix doesn't matter.  In particular, if we let $y = \Phi x$, then we have $\|y\| = \|x\|$, so saying 
$$
\|A\Phi x\|^2 = \alpha\|x\|^2
$$
is the same as saying
$$
\|Ay\|^2 = \alpha \|y\|^2
$$
So, I will henceforth assume that $\Phi$ isn't there.

---

What you want, it seems are bounds on the ratio
$\frac{\|Ax\|^2}{\|x\|^2}$, where $x$ is assumed to be non-zero.  In fact, the lowest possible upper bound and highest possible lower bound are given precisely by the square singular values of $A$.  That is:
$$
s_n(A)^2 \leq
\frac{\|Ax\|^2}{\|x\|^2} \leq 
s_1(A)^2
$$
and we can always choose an $x$ such that equality holds for either of the two bounds.

In order for us to be able to choose a constant $\alpha$ that works for all $x$, we need to have $s_1(A) = s_n(A)$.  This occurs precisely the columns of $A$ are of equal length and are mutually orthogonal.  In particular, if $m<n$, this can only hold if $A = 0_{m \times n}$.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer.  Here's a few lines of MATLAB code I tried to verify:   `ROWS = 10;  
COLS = 5;  

A = randn(ROWS);  
[A,~] = qr(A);  
A = A(1:COLS,:);  
S = svd(A);  
x = randn(ROWS);  
b = A*dct(x);  

fprintf('SVD Upper Bound: %f SVD Lower Bound: %f Actual Ratio: %f\n', ...
    S(1)^2,S(COLS)^2,(norm(x))^2/(norm(b))^2);  
`  The singular values are always 1, but the ratio goes above that (between 1 and 2).

Comment: You seem to have $m > n$ here

Comment: Oops, I mixed up my notation in the code, but I was generating the model I wanted. I want $m$ rows and $n$ columns, where $m \lt n$.  The corrected code (though it gets the same result) is `ROWS = 5;
COLS = 10;

A = randn(COLS);
[A,~] = qr(A);
A = A(1:ROWS,:);
S = svd(A);
x = randn(COLS);
b = A*dct(x);

fprintf('SVD Upper Bound: %f SVD Lower Bound: %f Actual Ratio: %f\n', ...
    S(1)^2,S(ROWS)^2,(norm(x))^2/(norm(b))^2);
`  I appreciate your help so far.

Comment: If $m<n$, you should always find that the lowest singular value is $0$.